# Symfony's NumberType as HTML5 input field and a custom locale setting

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, locale

My application prefers `de` as **locale** to show numbers like 1.234.567,89 instead of 1,234,567.89 (or 1234567,89 instead of 1234567.89).

So i have changed the local parameter in the `config.yml`:

```
parameters:
    locale: de
```

Furthermore i use the **NumberType** to generate my form fields:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('myNumber', NumberType::class, [
            'label'    => 'Tax [EURO]',
            'required' => false,
            'scale'    => 2,
            'attr'     => array(
                'min'  => 0,
                'max'  => 9999.99,
                'step' => 0.01,
            ),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now the value of *myNumber* is shown as a german formatted number the generated HTML5 input field and the field does either work nor show any number. If i change back the locale to `en` everything is working fine.

IMO the html5 input field needs to be filled with an english formatted number. But how can i manage to output the number not as german?

#### Summary

With locale `de` the field does *not* work. The value is not displayed in the generated input field although the value attribute is filled correctly with the german formatted number: `<input type="number" value="1234567,89">`

With locale `en` the field works: `<input type="number" value="1234567.89">`

Funny fact: My browsers (Firefox 45.9.0 and Google Chrome v54.0.2840.71, debian/64-bit) detect my computer's locale settings *de* and shows the the number as a german formatted number even if i ste the application's locale to `en` (onlinput fields of type `number`)

Adding the lang attribute `<html lang="{{ app.request.locale }}">` did not helped.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the problem... do not use symfony's **`NumberType`** for ***HTML5*** input elements of type `number`!

Instead use the common `TextType` form type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('myNumber', TextType::class, [...]);
}
```

and add the attribute `type="number"` via the template. For instance with the Twig engine you can use following code:

```
{{ form_widget(form.myNumber, {'type':'number', 'lang': app.request.locale}) }}
```

Comment: I don't know if it is the recommended way , but it does the trick ;) Thks

Comment: Don't set field type in twig, it's much better to do this in php file.
And since Symfony 4 there is option to set html5 behavior on number file.

Answer (score 0):

This is old question, but there is no correct answer yet and problem can still exists.

Since Symfony 4.3 there is introduced an option 'html5'. "False" par default but if set to true, the HTML input will be rendered as a native HTML5 type="number" form.
https://symfony.com/doc/4.x/reference/forms/types/number.html#input

So in your case:

```
$builder->add('myNumber', NumberType::class, [
        'label'    => 'Tax [EURO]',
        'html5'    => true,
        'required' => false,
        'scale'    => 2,
        'attr'     => array(
            'min'  => 0,
            'max'  => 9999.99,
            'step' => 0.01,
        ),
    ]);
```

Regards