# How to fix the size of field to maxlength using form_widget

Tags: symfony, twig, maxlength

I am using form_widget to render my field , what I want is to limit the digits to 5
(not to let the person type more then 8 digits ) somthing like maxlengh in html

I have tried :

```
 {{ form_widget(form.telMobile, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control','placeholder' :'number - 8 digits',  'size' : '8' }}) }}

 {{ form_widget(form.telMobile, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control','placeholder' :'number - 8 digits',  'maxlength' : '8'  }}) }}
```

How could I limit the number of digits before validation?

**update:still not working**

this is my form builder

```
->add('telMobile', null,array('label' => 'common.label.telmobile', 'required' => true ,'attr' => ['pattern' => '/^[0-9]{8}$/']))
```

and I have tried also to add the pattern to the widget :

```
 {{ form_widget(form.telMobile, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control','placeholder' :'Téléphone mobile - 8 chiffres', pattern' : '/^[0-9]{8}$/' }}) }}
```

as you see in the picture I still can type more than 8 digits

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Since you are passing `null` to the `FormBuilder` as your field type, Symfony's *Type Guessing System* is kicking in. This tries to guess the appropiate form control for your field based on its definition. Judging by the arrows in the screenshot, it's resolving to `NumberType`, and a numeric field doesn't have a `maxlength` property.

To fix this, you'll have to explicitly set it to `TextType`:

```
->add('telMobile', TextType::class, array(
    'label' => 'common.label.telmobile', 'required' => true, 
    'attr' => ['pattern' => '/^[0-9]{8}$/', 'maxlength' => 8])
 )
```

This will, however, come with its own tradeoffs: now the input will be limited in length but the user will be able to input letters. If this is not desireable and you want to **reject** invalid input, you'll have to use a [javascript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357).

Comment: I have tested your code know it accept max 8 digits but even with the pattern it accept caracters (Which I coulsn't allowed it a telephone number) and when I validate a message appear : didn't respect the requested format

Comment: @Julie right, that's what the last paragraph was trying to explain. The user is able to introduce other characters, despite the browser giving a validation error. If you want the field to **reject** invalid input, you must use javascript. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357)

Answer (score 0):

This question is related more to html options of number input, you can use 'max' and 'min' parameters in input of type number

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="99999" />
```

so using form_widget it will look next:

```
 {{ form_widget(form.number, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control','placeholder' :'number - 5 digits','type':'number',  'max' : '99999'  }}) }}
```

But more comfy will be to create form field using [NumberType::class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44696981/symfonys-numbertype-as-html5-input-field-and-a-custom-locale-setting) and add 'attr' there.
Also if you need exactly 5 numbers , you can validate it using regex expression, but input type should be `"text"` then:

```
'pattern' : '[0-9]{5}'  -this will expect exactly 5 digits
```

To sum up, if you need it to be safe then better is to use regex on back-end side in symfony using validators. 
P.S. `maxlength` works if the input's type is text.

Comment: I am using  preg_match() on the backend but I want to block the user to type more digits in the input field before validation and the same for text field .PS I have tried you code it didn't work the user can type more than 5 digits

Comment: send the code where you create your form with a form builder, send the twig code and output html result of certain field and i will help you, add that code to the question.